# JPA query a class that implements another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I've been working on converting our system from manual hibernate to spring using JPA.
So far it has been going great. At some point I came across the need to query for all the instances of a class that implement another class.
Lets look at the following design:

**Base Class: Machine**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MACHINE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Machine")
public abstract class Machine implements Resource {
   // ...
}
```

**Interface: Monitorable**

```
public interface Monitorable {
   // ...
}
```

**Subclass: Linux**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Linux")
public class Linux extends Machine implements Monitorable {
    // ...
}
```

Using Hibernate it looked like this:

```
public static List<Machine> GetALL(Class<?> T) {
    // .. hibernate session stuff ..
    result = session.createCriteria(T).setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    // .. closing session and error handling.
}
```

I've got a working Machine repository and I can easily use findAll() and then filter, but it seems like a waste.

Whilst searching for an answer I found the following implementation of a repository which lets us retrieve all sub-classes.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseMachineRepo<EntityType extends Machine> extends CrudRepository<EntityType, Long> {

    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e")
    List<EntityType> findAllByType();
}
```

However, I don't quite see how to change this implementation to work for an interface instead of a class.

The closest I got was changing the signature:

```
public interface BaseMachineRepo<EntityType extends Machine & Monitorable> extends CrudRepository<EntityType, Long>
```

However this will not solve the issue since the type is not 'Monitorbale' but 'Linux'. It does not change the query, just enforces more restrictions on the caller.

Thanks.

Edit:

I am aware that an interface doesn't affect the table itself, otherwise I would've known how to query for it. On the other hand, writing a custom repo which would check if the type (for example `Linux`) is an `instanceof` the interface feels really wrong.

Comment: I dont get what you want to do with the Interface. As Linux implements Monitorable and not Machine i guess that not all subtypes of Machine need to implement Monitorable, so you canno make this generic. If you want to query for concrete subtype then use the JPQL TYPE operator like this: `SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE TYPE(m) = Linux`. I think the type can be parametrized here.

Comment: I want to query for all the machines that implement `Monitorable`. Linux is not the only sub-class which implements it and writing down the list manually in a specific query is a pitfall.
Any other method which is not query based is inefficient.
Adding a column for indication would enable to query for it however it won't reflect reality and I'd rather not change the table.

Comment: I guess JPA is not aware of the `Monitorable` interface. I would try to introduce another intermediate abstract class like `MonitorableMachine` which would extend `Machine` and implement `Monitorable` and query for this class and it's subtypes which would then be `Monitorable`.

Comment: I'd rather not create another type of class since the architecture is complicated as it is.. Thanks for the advice though, I'll just go with reflection and a custom repo. When I'm done I'll post my code for anyone else whose interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution that I ended up writing:

```
public class MachineRepoImpl implements MachineRepoCustom {

@Autowired
private MachineRepo machineRepo;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public List<Machine> findMonitorables() {
    List<Machine> machines = machineRepo.findAll();
    Map<String, Monitorable> beansOfType = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Monitorable.class);
    Collection<Monitorable> monitorables = beansOfType.values();
    Set<Class<? extends Monitorable>> set = new HashSet<>(); 
    List<Machine> result = new ArrayList<Machine>();

    // parses monitorable classes
    for(Monitorable m : monitorables)
    {
        set.add(m.getClass());
    }

    // checks whether the entry in the table is monitorable 
    for (Machine machine : machines) {
        if (set.contains(machine.getClass())) {
            result.add(machine);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```